# Angular insert multiple rows using mat multiple select

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to add a movie with its actors, the api is working fine i can add the actors in postman, like this

```
 "actors_Movies": [
    {
      "actorId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
    },
   {
      "actorId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
    },
  ]
```

when i make a multiple select in angular i get this array

```
"actors_Movies":[
 "actorId": ['9feabd99-4208-48b3-12a8-08daea5d7ee4', '903e246e-175b-4916-12a9-08daea5d7ee4']
]
```

which is wrong. i tried this

```
export interface MovieForCreation {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  cinemaId: string;
  producerId: string;
  actors_Movies: ActorMovieForCreation[];
}
```

```
export interface ActorMovieForCreation {
  actorId: string;
}
```

```
  comparer(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    return o1 && o2 ? o1.label === o2.label : o2 === o2;
  }
```

```
private executeMovieCreation = (movieFormValue: any) => {

    let movie: MovieForCreation = {
      id: movieFormValue.id,
      name: movieFormValue.name,
      cinemaId: movieFormValue.cinemaId,
      producerId: movieFormValue.producerId,

      actors_Movies: [
        {
          actorId: movieFormValue.actorId
        }
      ]
    };
```

```
   <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Actor</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="actorId"  [compareWith]="comparer" multiple>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let actor of actors" [value]="actor.id">
            {{actor.fullName}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

and am getting this:

```
"actors_Movies":[
 "actorId": ['9feabd99-4208-48b3-12a8-08daea5d7ee4', '903e246e-175b-4916-12a9-08daea5d7ee4']
]
```

and this is what i want to achieve

```
 "actors_Movies": [
    {
      "actorId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
    },
   {
      "actorId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform an array of strings to an array of objects.

```js
let movie: MovieForCreation = {
  // Properties
  actors_Movies: movieFormValue.actorId.map(x => ({ actorId: x }))
};
```